# Display teasers in a details element

Tags: views

I have a view which is displaying nodes in the teaser view mode.

I would like to to have all those teasers inserted into a details HTML element.

This is the code I am using.

```php
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['content'] = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => $variables['label'][0]['#context']['value'],
    'content'=>$variables['content'],
  ];
}
```

I tried to use the following code without success.

```php
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['content'] = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => $variables['label'][0]['#context']['value'],
    'content' => [
      '#theme' => 'node',
      '#node'=> $variables['node'],
      '#view_mode'=> 'teaser',
    ],
  ];
}
```

The idea was to reuse the teaser template. When doing this, the site is taking too much time to display the page. (In fact, it doesn't display it.)

The same happens when I use `'content' =>\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->view($node,'teaser')`.

As only the first snippet works, I added a template suggestion for the details element in order to re-create the layout of the teaser template.

Is it the best approach?

Comment: Why not just create a new view mode and a template with the markup you want? You don't need to call the viewBuilder service in preprocess node. That hook is fired for any node being rendered in any view mode. Create a view mode and set that view mode as the one you want in a view showing entities rendered, that is step one. Then add a twig template with desired markup for that view mode. Then you don't need a hook.

Comment: I have 2 arguments against it: (1) This is true for "easy" markup, but it is not easy to add a markup for a details element because, the details element is also preprocessed and there are some added JS. (2) Code re-use: the details element is already coded somewhere, why should I redo the same code in a template. Conclusion: maybe you have a nice idea on how to insert a details element in a twig template... In this case you answer is totally valid.